# Python max() - largest element in list is not the same as largest in CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, csv, element

My prime list file is in CSV format, delimiter is comma, and has data for the primes upto 50000. The file also has random line breaks.

Issue: 49999 is the largest number in the file, but largest element in `primes_list` is 9973!

[Later every prime in `Primes` list will be converted to `long` type, and use the values in a for loop. `for prime in Primes`]

Hence my problem is what I'm doing wrong with the below minimal python code?

Python version is 2.76, running on Linux Mint 17.

Edit - Corrected code after comments;

```
import csv

def factorise()
    primes=[]
    with open(primefile,'r') as csvfile:
        primes_data=csvfile.read().replace('\n','').split(',')
        primes=primes_data
        print('Number of elements is: '+str(len(primes)))
        print('First element is: '+primes[0])
        print('Last element is: '+primes[-1])
        csvfile.close()
        print('Largest element is: '+max(primes))
```

Output example;

```
Number of elements is: 5134
First element is: 2
last element is: 49999
Largest element is: 9973
```

Comment: Primes_data=csvfile.read().replace('\n','').split(',') uses Primes_data but Primes=Prime_data does not. Is this in your code or just a typo here. Note the difference in pluralization. Also csvfile.close is a function and you are simply making a reference to the location in memory. You need to call it, csvfile.close()

Comment: Not sure what you mean by double quotes. You should avoid naming your variables with capitalizations, are those just variables because that is a class naming convention. There are a lot of issues in your snippet. I would get the proper Python conventions implemented and fix your typos, especially if this is in your source code.

Comment: Corrected. Both of those were typos on here. Question still stands

Comment: Have some output snippets? Ensure that primes is the correct type and holds the correct values. Your assigning primes_data to primes which may not have the intended results you are expecting. Is len(primes) and primes[0] giving you the correct output? What is primes[-1] giving you, a value from the list, garbage data, exceptions?

Comment: Updated question with output as requested. Laat element should be 49999.

Comment: How do I find out what type `primes` should be? Currently I believe just using it as a variable for holding the list for `primes_data`

Comment: I have corrected code further & updated title & question.

Comment: You're comparing strings and `9973` is the max value in lexicographical order. Convert those values to numbers before you start to work with them.

Answer (score 0):

So what's special about 9973?  Did you look at the file and is there a new line there?

At any rate, what you probably want is [csv.reader()](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/csv.html) rather than the standard IO.read()

```
import csv

def factorise():
    first_element = int()
    total_list = list()

    with open("primefile.csv", "r") as file:
        primes = csv.reader(file)
        for line in primes:
            if not first_element:
                print('First element is: %s' % line[0])
                first_element = line[0]
            total_list.extend(line)
        print('Number of elements is: %s' % len(total_list))
        print('Last element is: %s' % line[-1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    factorise()
```

I don't have your source so I can't test this, but it seems like it should work.

EDIT: fixed a couple stupid bugs